# calling a view without passing request

Tags: python, django

I have a view that is called like this.

```
def device_check(request, d, i):
# A bunch of stuff the view does
```

When i call this view by default it works perfect no issues, then i have another function that generates some data and tries to call that function to check and i keep getting the error that its not passing enough arguments, since i am trying to use it like this

```
def test_function(request):
    test = device_check("test", "i-1799")
```

And i understand the error is being caused because i am not passing it the request parameter like so

```
device_check(request, "test", "i-1799")
```

But i have no idea how i would pass it the request parameter from within another function.

Is there a better way of doing this, or a way around that?

Comment: So why does the `device_check` needs a `request` parameter? What is the "bunch of stuff" doing with the `request`?

Comment: one thing that i am doing in that function is grabbing the referer, with this request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not common case or best practice to call a view function from another view function. You probably want to put the common logic in another utility function so you can reuse across views if needed.

But in your case, you can create another http request object within your test function.

```
from django.http import HttpRequest

def test_function(request):
    # Create a new HttpRequest object
    fake_request = HttpRequest()

    # set attributes of the fake request as needed i.e. user, path ..
    fake_request.user = request.user  # pass the user to the request

    # Call device_check with the fake request
    test = device_check(fake_request, "test", "i-1799")
```

Comment: I like the option of using a utility function, how would you recommend i would do something like that?